# Getting range from radar weather data NetCDF file (Python)

Tags: python, netcdf, precipitation, radar

I am trying to find the range distance from the NetCDF files of a radar looking at precipitation data. Below I have attached the header of all data values the NetCDF file provides.[image]

I see the file provides all azimuth values which I can pull out, but I am unsure what I need to do to find the range.
The values "Elevation", "Time", "StartRange", "TxLength", and "StartGate" are all constants. My thought is to use "Usecs", then find the range by using: range = (½ ⋅ Usecs ⋅ c), where c = speed of light. My thought is the range is equal to half the time it takes to reach the target, times the speed of light--to get the distance of the target from the radar, the range. Below I have included a photo of the values in Usecs. I believe they may be scaled to nanoseconds since the radar distance max is only a few km.
[image]

I have been using np.linspace(0,626,626) as a placeholder for my data until I figure out the problem because I have been making Height vs Azimuth graphs. Where 626 is the number of pixels, the gate dimension size, and Height I get from Height = (Range ⋅ sin( θ)).

Is there anything else or a radar range equation to plug in values presented in this file?